# Capturing image using custom buttons in cameraoverlayview in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

Thanks in advance.

I have created a custom toolbar on `cameraOverlayView`. One of the toolbar buttons will trigger the `takeSnap` method –

```
-(IBAction)takeSnap
{
    NSLog(@"take snap called");
    [self.picker takePicture];  



- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    UIImage *image = img;
    NSLog(@"image : %@",image);
}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    NSLog(@"Did cancel called");  
}
```

But it is not calling the delegate methods after capturing. The view continues to remain in capture mode. If any one know the reason please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very likely that you haven't assigned a delegate properly.

Comment: Thanks for ur response.                            self.picker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.picker.delegate = self;                                            I assigned the deleate like this .

Comment: Check whether `self.picker` is `nil` in `takePicture`. Are you not getting any of those logs?

Comment: Thank u deepak. Now it is working. self.picker is not nil.I have checked every thing.But the problem is with iphone.